# Query to collect the recent unique TimeSampled rows using inner joins for multiple servers in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, join, query

Dears,
I have written below inner join query to get the data from my database tables. But output of this data is coming up with almost 3k lines. Output is below. I need data in only unique recent "TimeSampled" rows

[image]

```
select DISTINCT DisplayName, ObjectName, CounterName, InstanceName, SampleValue, max(TimeSampled) as TimeSampled
from PerformanceDataAllView pdv with (NOLOCK)
inner join PerformanceCounterView pcv on pdv.performancesourceinternalid = pcv.performancesourceinternalid
inner join BaseManagedEntity bme on pcv.ManagedEntityId = bme.BaseManagedEntityId
where ObjectName = 'Processor' AND TimeSampled >= DATEADD(MINUTE,-5,GETDATE())
AND DisplayName Like '%'
group by  [PATH], [DisplayName], [ObjectName], [CounterName], [InstanceName], [SampleValue]
```

How I can retrieve results with only last Time Sampled rows with respect to DisplayName. I have almost 5k servers (DisplayName) like this to retrieve the data.

Request to need to a help to achieve this.

Comment: Replace `SampleValue` (it seems it is ) with `FIRST_VALUE(SampleValue) OVER (PARTITION BY DisplayName ORDER BY TimeSampled DESC)`, remove it from GROUP BY and (maybe?) add DISTINCT. If `CounterName` and/or `InstanceName` can differ within the same `DisplayName` do the same with them.

Comment: This is the second time you've posted this (https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/242045/181661)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION` can allow you to select the top row per distinct value, in this case the `DisplayName` by only selecting where the `ROW_NUMBER() = 1` in an outer query.

I've included this using your query below for an idea, you may need to adjust further to suite your needs.

```
SELECT DisplayName, ObjectName, CounterName, InstanceName, SampleValue, TimeSampled
FROM
(
    select DISTINCT DisplayName, ObjectName, CounterName, InstanceName, SampleValue, max(TimeSampled) as TimeSampled
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DisplayName ORDER BY TimeSampled DESC) DispCount
    from PerformanceDataAllView pdv with (NOLOCK)
    inner join PerformanceCounterView pcv on pdv.performancesourceinternalid = pcv.performancesourceinternalid
    inner join BaseManagedEntity bme on pcv.ManagedEntityId = bme.BaseManagedEntityId
    where ObjectName = 'Processor' AND TimeSampled >= DATEADD(MINUTE,-5,GETDATE())
    AND DisplayName Like '%'
    group by  [PATH], [DisplayName], [ObjectName], [CounterName], [InstanceName], [SampleValue]
) s
WHERE s.DispCount = 1
```

Comment: Thanks alot Liber. Your query has worked for me with minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot Liber. Your query has worked for me with minor changes.

```
SELECT DisplayName, ObjectName, CounterName, InstanceName, SampleValue, TimeSampled
FROM
(
    select DISTINCT bme.DisplayName , pcv.ObjectName, pcv.CounterName, pcv.InstanceName, pdv.SampleValue, max(pdv.TimeSampled) as TimeSampled,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bme.DisplayName ORDER BY pdv.TimeSampled DESC) DispCount
    from PerformanceDataAllView pdv with (NOLOCK)
    inner join PerformanceCounterView pcv on pdv.performancesourceinternalid = pcv.performancesourceinternalid
    inner join BaseManagedEntity bme on pcv.ManagedEntityId = bme.BaseManagedEntityId
    where ObjectName = 'Processor' AND TimeSampled >= DATEADD(MINUTE,-15,GETDATE())
    AND DisplayName Like '%'
    group by  bme.PATH, bme.DisplayName, pcv.ObjectName, pcv.CounterName, pcv.InstanceName, pdv.SampleValue,pdv.TimeSampled
) s
WHERE s.DispCount = 1 
order by TimeSampled desc
```